# Shell BASH---SHA256 Hash Collisions occur in file extraction

Tags: bash, shell, hash, sha256, hash-collision

I use sha256 hash value to encrypt a password( no matter digit form or char form ).
when I unzip the password-protected file, I can use at least two different hash to unzip my file -- it occurs a Hash collision. Although there is no searching point out this situation, I know md5 and sha-1 have hash collision. **so what is the problem?**

### Case1: I use 5566 sha256 hash zip my file

```
zip -P be41b7f1fa56ba2b0582910053c86cf6ee7e311efc51300220df0918bb9a287b abc.zip abc
```

***Reference* Sha256(0138) = 687d579d0992a7895190ad126ba8051704753bdc85d52481a83da4670e2321d7**

***Reference* Sha256(5566) = be41b7f1fa56ba2b0582910053c86cf6ee7e311efc51300220df0918bb9a287b**

However, apart from 5566 hash value, I also can use 0138 hash value to unzip this file. The following code both success in file extraction.

```
     unzip -P 687d579d0992a7895190ad126ba8051704753bdc85d52481a83da4670e2321d7 abc.zip
     unzip -P be41b7f1fa56ba2b0582910053c86cf6ee7e311efc51300220df0918bb9a287b abc.zip
```

### Case2: I can use 'daniel' sha256 hash and 'pivate' sha256 hash to unzip a file.

Thank you for your attention. Hope someone can solve my problems.
I am doing a password brute-forcing assignment, and I cannot get the correct cracked password
 because of the above problem.

[image: PHOTO]

[image]

Comment: Can it unzip using other strings as the password? Was your version of zip built with support for encryption?

Comment: Can you replicate this with other compression tools that understand the zip format, like `7z`?

Comment: And are you sure the zip file you're using has encrypted files (`zipinfo -v T3/quiz_cvs.zip` should tell you)?

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]
empty zip files may lead to problems in unzip.